# Isolate brown by rgb values

Tags: colors, photoshop

I am looking to isolate "brown" colors by rgb values. Not just 1 brown color, but the wide spectrum of colors that are perceived as brown - tan, suede, dirt, etc.

Any ideas on how to do this? I'm thinking that maybe if Red is less than 128, and Green is between 70 and 138, and blue is less than 128, than it appears brown. Something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really simple heuristic would be something like, in pythony pseudocode

```
def isBrown(red, green, blue):

  # Kind of maximum lightness
  if blue > parameter_1
    return False

  # how green or red tinted can it be
  if absolute_value(red - green) > parameter_2:
    return False

  # Light brown is just yellow or orange
  if maximum_of(red, green) > parameter_3:
    return False
  else:
    return True
```

The tune parameters 1 through 3 until it works nicely. Perhaps replace `if absolute_value(red - green) > parameter_2:` with `if absolute_value(red - green*parameter_2b) > parameter_2a:` so that more greeny or reddy ones are selected depending on `parameter_2b`. Perhaps change `maximum_of` to something else. etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what you consider to be brown. It is a colour category for which there is rather high inter-subject variability and strong contextual effects (colours next to it changes how it looks).

Think you need to use something like this: http://www.colorpicker.com/ and look at the shape of the colours you decide on and then work out how to express that algorithmically.

Comment: Thanks, Lucas. In this application, I won't be able to control what colors are displayed next to the possible browns- and I hadn't thought about that. I'm wondering if anyone has attempted something like this algorithmically before, so I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: They have, and with radically different assumptions and degrees of sophistication. That is the problem. It depends completely on what you are doing and why you are doing it. If you just want a heuristic that kind of works do something like testing whether numbers are in a given range. I recommend you look at this: http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~kay/claire7.pdf but also, see my other answer.